# Create a full screen ion-button with span tags inside with display:block

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an Ionic Button full screen div that has other span tags inside it.
I tried using 
 I tried using display:block but no matter what the words center inline the middle.
How can I add make my spans a display:block item?

Html

```
<ion-content padding>
   <div ion-button (tap)="onTap()" class="buttNext">
     <span class="fullButt">{{corrObj.isCorr}}</span>
     <span class="fullButt">Score is {{corrObj.score}}</span>
     <span class="fullButt">Tap Screen to continue</span>
   </div>
 </ion-content>
```

CSS

```
.buttNext{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  opacity:1;
  background:gray;
 }

.fullButt{
  display: block;
  background: none;
  font-size:30px;
  color:white;
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Since *"no matter what the words center inline the middle."* this is wrong

Comment: Well that is what was happening

Comment: Then, what do you want on your screen and what is happening now?

Comment: I changed the ion content into just being a whole button instead. Thank you though

Comment: In your next question, please ask for what you want instead of throwing around styles, for example: "my content isn't jn the center of the screen" or "i want my content in the center of the screen", makes it easier to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a button fill the screen instead I just made the  a button itself.
This worked perfect for me and accomplished what I needed

```
<ion-content padding (tap)="onTap()" id="fullAns">
 <div class="ansCont">
   <span id="correct" class="fullButt">{{corrObj.isCorr}}</span>
   <span id="score" class="fullButt">Score is {{corrObj.score}}</span>
   <span id="tap" class="fullButt">Tap Anywhere to continue</span>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```